# HTML not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a little HTML doc. and whenever you click the button, the text from the input element will appear in a green color, but the function does not start.

```
<html>
<body style="width: 500px; ">
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function func(){
          document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = 

          document.getElementById("input").value;
          }
        </script>               
        <p style="color: green;" id="paragraph"></p>
        <input style="height: 30px; width: 480px; border-layout: solid green" id="input"><br>
        <button style="border-radius: 0px; border: solid grey 1px; 

        background-color: yellow;" onclick="func()">Echo Txt</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by function does not start? Please elaborate.

Comment: Your code actually work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOmyze

Comment: HTML works quite well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code below seems to be working.

What I have done is clean up some of your CSS. There is no such thing as `border-layout` though (so I've removed it).

```js
function func() {
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

```css
#input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 480px;
}
#paragraph {
  color: green;
}
.mybutton {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: solid grey 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <p id="paragraph"></p>
  <input id="input">
  <br>
  <button class="mybutton" onclick="func()">Echo Txt</button>
</div>
```